Physical Moon Earth System, problems with Moon's orbit
I am trying to obtain the trajectories of the orbit of earth and moon around the Sun using LeapFrog. I have managed to obtain the correct orbit of the Earth but in the moon case I haven't been able to make it orbit the Earth while both orbit the Sun, I think it might be a problem of initial conditions but I am not sure, this is the code that I have written:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double Grav = 6.6726e-11;        // m^3/kg/s^2 (Universal gravitational constant)
double Msun = 1.989e30;          // kg
double Mearth = 5.973e24;        // kg
double Mmoon = 7.349e22;         // kg
double Dse = 1.496e11;           // distance Sun-Earth in meters
double Dem = 3.844e8;            // distance Earth-Moon in meters
int nsteps = 100;                  // Timesteps per orbit


void LeapFrog(int n)
{
    // Initial Conditions
    double x0 = Dse;
    double y0 = 0;

    double vx0 = 0;
    double vy0 = sqrt(Grav * Msun / Dse);

    double px0 = Mearth * vx0;
    double py0 = Mearth * vy0;

    // Initial Conditions for Moon
    double xm0 = Dse + Dem;
    double ym0 = 0;

    double vxm0 = sqrt(Grav * Mearth / Dem);  // La velocidad en x es opuesta a la velocidad orbital de la Tierra
    double vym0 = vy0;   // La velocidad en y es igual a la velocidad orbital de la Tierra

    double pxm0 = Mmoon * vxm0;
    double pym0 = Mmoon * vym0;

    // Timestep
    double dt = (2 * 3.141592654 * Dse / vy0) / nsteps;      // fraction of a year

    
    // Create a file for saving the coordinates of Earth
    ofstream earthFile("LFEarth.dat");
    // Create a file for saving the coordinates of Moon
    ofstream moonFile("LFMoon.dat");

    earthFile << x0 << " " << y0 << '\n';
    moonFile << xm0 << " " << ym0 << '\n';

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // Update Earth position
        double x = x0 + dt * px0 / (2 * Mearth);
        double y = y0 + dt * py0 / (2 * Mearth);

        // Update Moon position
        double xm = xm0 + dt * pxm0 / (2 * Mmoon);
        double ym = ym0 + dt * pym0 / (2 * Mmoon);

        // Calculate distances to the Sun
        double r_earth_sun = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        double r_moon_sun = sqrt(xm * xm + ym * ym);
        double r_moon_earth = sqrt((xm-x)*(xm-x) + (ym-y)*(ym-y));

        // Update Earth momentum
        double px = px0 - dt * Grav * Msun * Mearth * x / pow(r_earth_sun, 3) - dt * Grav * Mmoon * Mearth * (x - xm) / pow(r_moon_earth, 3);
        double py = py0 - dt * Grav * Msun * Mearth * y / pow(r_earth_sun, 3) - dt * Grav * Mmoon * Mearth * y / pow(r_moon_earth, 3);

        // Update Moon momentum
        double pxm = pxm0 - dt * Grav * (Msun * Mmoon) * (xm) / pow(r_moon_sun, 3) - dt * Grav * (Mearth * Mmoon) * (xm - x) / pow(r_moon_earth, 3);
        double pym = pym0 - dt * Grav * (Msun * Mmoon) * (ym) / pow(r_moon_sun, 3) - dt * Grav * (Mearth * Mmoon) * (ym - y) / pow(r_moon_earth, 3);

        // Another Step for Earth position
        double x2 = x + dt * px / (2 * Mearth);
        double y2 = y + dt * py / (2 * Mearth);

        // Another Step for Moon position
        double xm2 = xm + dt * pxm / (2 * Mmoon);
        double ym2 = ym + dt * pym / (2 * Mmoon);

        earthFile << x2 << " " << y2 << std::endl;
        moonFile << xm2 << " " << ym2 << std::endl;

        // Initialise the values for the following step
        x0 = x2;
        y0 = y2;

        xm0 = xm2;
        ym0 = ym2;

        px0 = px;
        py0 = py;

        pxm0 = pxm;
        pym0 = pym;
    }
    // Close the files
    earthFile.close();
    moonFile.close();
}

int main()
{
    LeapFrog(nsteps * 10);                   // Ten orbits
    return 0;
}

And this is what I have obtained:

I expected to get the moon to orbit the Earth while they both orbit the Sun.

Can you please also write down the differential equations you are solving with your algorithm? If you solve them with some external tools, like Mathematica or Matlab, using higher order Runge-Kutta methods, do you get correct results?

Didn't check your code, but I suspect problem is time step. To simulate earth orbiting sun best time step is in scale of couple days. Now in case of the moon this will fail completely since this time step is simply to large and LeapFrog approximation is not good enough. So please provide simulation parameters as numbers with proper units.

https://godbolt.org/z/fKxcsGjd7 3.6 days when one rotation takes 29 days is definitely to big time step. Basically after 9 steps moon have to take full orbit around earth.

There seems to be a problem with initial conditions: you shift the Moon relative to Earth along X axis (xm0 = Dse + Dem) which means its initial velocity relative to Earth must be along Y axis. But your initial velocity is along X axis as well (vxm0 = sqrt(Grav * Mearth / Dem)): your moon starts flying away from Earth.

There's also an obvious typo in py calculation.

Sidenote: look up function hypot and replace the sqrt calls.

@j6t: I am not sure hypot is better. It avoids overflow, but that costs time. If we are operating in a domain where the sum of the squares will not overflow, what benefit would hypot provide? It might read more nicely, but that could be done with a user-defined function.

@EricPostpischil It allows you to write the linear form of the arguments instead of the squares. Shorter code, fewer errors. Yes, a user-defined function would do that, too.

There are a number of things wrong with your code ... and your expectations.
The following have all been alluded to by other people in comments:
(1) You need more steps per (earth) orbit. After all, there are 12 lunar months in a year (roughly).
(2) The expression for py is wrong, where it needs relative displacement of moon and earth.
(3) Your initial conditions are slightly wrong (alternative version sketched as a comment in the code below.)
But not mentioned yet are your expectations in the end.
(4) If you plot BOTH earth and moon paths on the same graph, then, since the distance between earth and sun is about 500 times that between earth and moon, you would need both a monitor and eyesight better than I possess to see a difference in orbits.
In the code below I add another output file "LFrelative.dat" (sorry!) which shows just the moon's position relative to the earth. Plotting this gives the orbit of our nearest celestial body - note that the scale is completely different.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const double Grav = 6.6726e-11;        // m^3/kg/s^2 (Universal gravitational constant)
const double Msun = 1.989e30;          // kg
const double Mearth = 5.973e24;        // kg
const double Mmoon = 7.349e22;         // kg
const double Dse = 1.496e11;           // distance Sun-Earth in meters
const double Dem = 3.844e8;            // distance Earth-Moon in meters
const int nsteps = 1000;               // Timesteps per orbit
const double PI = 4 * atan( 1.0 );


void LeapFrog(int n)
{
    // Initial Conditions
    double x0 = Dse;
    double y0 = 0;

    double vx0 = 0;
    double vy0 = sqrt(Grav * Msun / Dse);

    double px0 = Mearth * vx0;
    double py0 = Mearth * vy0;

    // Initial Conditions for Moon
    double xm0 = x0;                             //                           <--M
    double ym0 = Dem;                            //                              |
    double vxm0 = sqrt(Grav * Mearth / Dem);     //  S---------------------------E
    double vym0 = vy0;                      

    double pxm0 = Mmoon * vxm0;
    double pym0 = Mmoon * vym0;

    // Timestep
    double dt = (2 * PI * Dse / vy0) / nsteps;      // fraction of a year
    
    // Create a file for saving the coordinates of Earth
    ofstream earthFile("LFEarth.dat");
    // Create a file for saving the coordinates of Moon
    ofstream moonFile("LFMoon.dat");
    ofstream relativeFile("LFRelative.dat");

    earthFile    << x0       << " " << y0        << '\n';
    moonFile     << xm0      << " " << ym0       << '\n';
    relativeFile << xm0 - x0 << " " << ym0 - y0  << '\n';

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // Update Earth position
        double x = x0 + dt * px0 / (2 * Mearth);
        double y = y0 + dt * py0 / (2 * Mearth);

        // Update Moon position
        double xm = xm0 + dt * pxm0 / (2 * Mmoon);
        double ym = ym0 + dt * pym0 / (2 * Mmoon);

        // Calculate distances to the Sun
        double r_earth_sun = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        double r_moon_sun = sqrt(xm * xm + ym * ym);
        double r_moon_earth = sqrt((xm-x)*(xm-x) + (ym-y)*(ym-y));

        // Update Earth momentum
        double px = px0 - dt * Grav * Msun * Mearth * x / pow(r_earth_sun, 3) - dt * Grav * Mmoon * Mearth * (x - xm) / pow(r_moon_earth, 3);
        double py = py0 - dt * Grav * Msun * Mearth * y / pow(r_earth_sun, 3) - dt * Grav * Mmoon * Mearth * (y - ym) / pow(r_moon_earth, 3);

        // Update Moon momentum
        double pxm = pxm0 - dt * Grav * Msun * Mmoon * xm / pow(r_moon_sun, 3) - dt * Grav * Mearth * Mmoon * (xm - x) / pow(r_moon_earth, 3);
        double pym = pym0 - dt * Grav * Msun * Mmoon * ym / pow(r_moon_sun, 3) - dt * Grav * Mearth * Mmoon * (ym - y) / pow(r_moon_earth, 3);

        // Another Step for Earth position
        double x2 = x + dt * px / (2 * Mearth);
        double y2 = y + dt * py / (2 * Mearth);

        // Another Step for Moon position
        double xm2 = xm + dt * pxm / (2 * Mmoon);
        double ym2 = ym + dt * pym / (2 * Mmoon);

        earthFile    << x2       << "  " << y2       << std::endl;
        moonFile     << xm2      << "  " << ym2      << std::endl;
        relativeFile << xm2 - x2 << "  " << ym2 - y2 << std::endl;

        // Initialise the values for the following step
        x0 = x2;
        y0 = y2;

        xm0 = xm2;
        ym0 = ym2;

        px0 = px;
        py0 = py;

        pxm0 = pxm;
        pym0 = pym;
    }
    // Close the files
    earthFile.close();
    moonFile.close();
    relativeFile.close();
}

int main()
{
    LeapFrog(nsteps * 10);             // Ten orbits
    return 0;
}

Earth and moon on SOLAR ORBIT scale:

Moon ORBIT RELATIVE TO THE EARTH - note the difference in scale:


That makes a lot of sense, I was very confused with that, thank you for your answer!
